# variable is only found once during jQuery iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, twig

I want one icon of each icon group to be marked with border on event hover.

The provided code works perfectly on first iteration. But on 2nd try it skips to the else-statement and does not find activeEl anymore.

Therefore it then only marks one icon with border not one of every icon group.

**This is the js-file:**

```
        const refinementData = el.dataset.identifier; // its for currentTarget and returns 'refinement' or 'tag'

        // example: if 'refinement' then...
        if (refinementData) {
            // activeEl is the node of the active <li>. it always returns the 1st <li>
            const activeEl = parent.find(`${this.opts.control}.active`)
            console.log("this is active el:", activeEl)

            activeEl.each((index, item) => {
                if (item.dataset.identifier === refinementData) {
                    item.classList.remove(this.opts.activeClass);
                    console.log("this is the if statement", item)
                }
            })
        } else {
            const elseEl = parent.find(this.opts.control).removeClass(this.opts.activeClass);
            console.log("this is the else statement:", elseEl)
        }

        el.classList.add(this.opts.activeClass);
```

**And this is the twig-file:**

```
                {# div that shows the refinement color && tag options #}
                <div class="refinement-options tag-options js-action-element">
                    <ul>
                        {% for refinement in concreteProduct.productOptions.refinements %}
                            {# create <li> with color of refinement key #}
                            {% if refinement.key != 'V00' %}<li class="with-icon without-text svg-refinement {{refinement.key|lower}} {{refinement.key == pre_config_refinement ? 'active': ''}} option"
                            data-refinement="{{refinement.key}}" data-identifier="refinement"></li>{% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}

                        {% for tag in concreteProduct.productOptions.tags %}
                            {# create <li> with tag icon #}
                            {% if tag.key != 'T00' %}<li class="with-icon without-text svg-tag {{tag.key|lower}} {{tag.key == pre_config_tag ? 'active': ''}} option" data-tag="{{tag.key}}" data-identifier="tag"></li>{% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

I simply cannot find a way to make this solution work several times in a row (which in my case would mean repeating the hover effect several times with same result).

Comment: const is a constant you can declare & assign it once during execution. but in you loop you are reassigning which is wrong.

Comment: I tried but its not the solution...

Comment: replace const with var or let

Comment: i did. its not the solution unfortunately.